# Use of Decode() if not equal condition in pl sql

Tags: plsql

I am working on cursors.
Now in that i have one task such as if column1=21 then column2 can be in ('item1','item2','item3') but if column1 is other than 21 then column2 can only be 'item1'. And both column1 and column2 is part of primary_key.

So i tried this approach..

I will provide any value in column2 from above 3 values and then in processing i will check if column1 is 21 then i can use any of above 3 values and if column2 is other than 21 then i have to use only 'item1'.

But as i am using this two columns in cursor and they are part of primary key and i have to fetch rowid in cursor to check duplicate record.

But i will not get rowid as i will change value of column2 in processing.

SO i am thinking to use decode() but i am not getting idea how to use it for this case:

```
if column1 =21 then
   column2:={item1,item2,item3}//any from this 3 values
end if;

if column1 <> 21 then
   column2:='item1'
end if;
```

Please suggest me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
column2 := DECODE(column1, 21, '{item1,item2,item3}', item1)
```

By the way, "any from this 3 values" - is non-deterministic which is why I entered the string `'{item1,item2,item3}'`.

If you know which one of these values you want - you can replace the string `'{item1,item2,item3}'` with that value.

Comment: Thank you so much... I used your approach by modifying it.

Comment: As you suggested, I used one value from 3 values because that value will come from one column so i have to use that column only.

Answer (score 0):

After discussion solution of above problem that i used is :

```
 declare
 column1 number :=21;
 column2 varchar2(50):='item2';\\This can be any value provided by user
 cursor c is 
    select DECODE(column1, 22, column2, 'item1') column2
      from dual;
 begin
   for rec in c
   loop
     dbms_output.put_line(rec.column2);
   end loop;
 end;
```